# Error in SQL syntax near %var

Tags: php, printf

**SOLVED**

I have a minor error in my query in php file and I need to fix either by hiding an error or by fixing mistake. What I have is this:

```
$findgroup = sprintf('SELECT * 
        person.id as iden,
       IF (person.place = "", "A specified person was not found", person.place
       ) as person.place
       FROM person
       WHERE %s',
       $findgroup, $office);
```

While this code is working as it should be, in a page I see an error "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 (which is [WHERE %s',]).

My question is either how to hide that error since query is still working or how to fix it if possible? Hope that's enough of code.

Comment: How does the resulting SQL statement look like?

Comment: "how to hide that error" - **Don't try and hide the errors. Handle the errors appropriately, especially on production!**

Comment: Missing comma after `SELECT *`

Comment: After entering id in table this query searches for that id and returns a place where a person lives. It works as it supposed to.

Comment: The query cannot be "working" if it throws that error. If it would be working, it wouldn't throw an error like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is you are passing in two params to `sprintf`, but only replacing one.

You only have one `%s`, but two params. Also you should make sure that the parameter you pass in is indeed a string (%s).

```
$findgroup = sprintf('SELECT * 
        person.id as iden,
       IF (person.place = "", "A specified person was not found", person.place
       ) as person.place
       FROM person
       WHERE %s',
       $office);
```

Comment: Let's say I need to get: 1. words 2. number. Which string should be used?

Comment: @EdvinTenovim Hey, for strings use `%s` and for numbers/integers use `%d`. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
$findgroup = sprintf('SELECT * 
    person.id as iden,
   IF (person.place = "", "A specified person was not found", person.place
   ) as person.place
   FROM person
   WHERE "%s" ',
   $findgroup, $office);
```